# TRANSPORT.RULES.RejectMessage; the message was rejected by organization policy

Tags: smtp, amazon-ses, email-headers, bounce, transport-security

Bounce Email Event Occurred.
From Email: no-reply@somedomain
Email Subject: Some subject
Bounced Recipients:
Emailaddress: example@somedomain
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Diagnosticcode: smtp;550 5.7.1 TRANSPORT.RULES.RejectMessage; the message was rejected by organization policy

Any one can help on this issue.

Comment: This usually means the receiving email server thinks you're a spammer. Could be related to the content of your emails, to your IP address, or that too many users have marked your previous emails a spam. Either way it's not a programming question and hence off-topic here. See [ask].